# Overwrite exclusion with non-exclusion in child POM

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

If I have an exclusion in my parent POM, something like this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.3</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
         <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

How would I get rid of that exclusion or unexclude in my child POM whatever I've excluded via parent POM?
I've tried an empty `<exclusions>` tag, hoping it would overwrite the entirety of the exclusion (with now none) coming from the parent, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out,
just include the dependency in the child POM, two negatives make a positive

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
   <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

In fact the first dependency doesn't even have to be restated, just the ones explicitly excluded in the parent POM.